# reading a dataset in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to do a pretty simple task, but unable to understand pandas behavior.
I am reading a UCI dataset in python using pandas:

```
data = pd.read_csv('UCI/breast-cancer-wisconsin.data', header=None)
```

Printing out the first row

```
data.values[0]
# array([1000025, 5, 1, 1, 1, 2, '1', 3, 1, 1, 2], dtype=object)
```

Why does it read the 7th column as string?
I tried the following:

```
print(pd.api.types.infer_dtype(data[6])) #returns string
```

It is a pretty simple dataset, directly downloaded form [this link](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml//machine-learning-databases/breast-cancer-wisconsin/breast-cancer-wisconsin.data), and all values appear integers to me. Then why is the 6th column interpreted as a string?

Comment: line 412 of the file has a '?' for column 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check unique values - there is character `?` for not exist value, so column is parsed to strings:

```
data = pd.read_csv('breast-cancer-wisconsin.data', header=None)[6]
print (data.unique())
['1' '10' '2' '4' '3' '9' '7' '?' '5' '8' '6']
```

Solution is add parameter `na_values='?'` for convert `?` to missing values:

```
data = pd.read_csv('breast-cancer-wisconsin.data', header=None, na_values='?')
print (data.dtypes)
0       int64
1       int64
2       int64
3       int64
4       int64
5       int64
6     float64
7       int64
8       int64
9       int64
10      int64
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

I loaded the dataset. Note that that specific column has a value "?". This results in dtype = object since it cannot automatically be casted to an integer.

```
data.iloc[:, 6].unique()
```

Results in:

```
array(['1', '10', '2', '4', '3', '9', '7', '?', '5', '8', '6'],
      dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

This probably due some string type of value in the column. To quickly test that, try this (**should result in error**)

```
df.iloc[:,6].astype("int")
```